# Adding a new Github organization in the S.O Careers?

Tags: support, jobs, github

I have a [StackOverflow careers profile](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/cnicodeme) and I already linked my GitHub profile with my S.O.C. profile.

But since then, I created a new Repository that I'd like to add to my S.O.C profile. If I go to "add Github", there is no things such as "Add a new organization", and if I click on "Update/add all my repositories" it doesn't find the one I created.

How do I make it so a new Github organization is visible to Stack Overflow Careers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go to that organization's "Members" page and make your profile in that page public.

steps:

- Go to Organization's github page
- Click on "Members" on the right side of the page (it's above the avatars)

[image]
The URL would be:

> `https://github.com/orgs/<orgname>/members`

And then you'll a listing of members with the status of their profile. Click "Make Public" to make your profile public. At that point you'll be able to add it to Stack Overflow Careers.